# How to populate js array with data from jsp

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to populate LatLng's with coords from jsp but i'm newbie in js.
Could You give me some hints how do this:)?

i have in my jsp google maps api v3 that show map and draw simple path

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      myOptions);

  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
                                new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
                                new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
                                new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
                                new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
                              ];

  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
}

function loadScript() {
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?xxx&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;

</script>
```

below im getting coords from my controller

```
<c:forEach items="${trackpoints}" var="coord">
<div>lat = ${coord.latitude}, lon = ${coord.longitude}</div>
</c:forEach>
```

now i want to replace hardcoded flightPlanCoordinates in google maps api with my coords from "trackpoints"

i spend few hours but with no luck;/

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just printing them out in the array constructor?

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [<c:forEach items="${trackpoints}" var="coord">
    new google.maps.LatLng(${coord.latitude}, ${coord.longitude}),
    </c:forEach>];
```

Remember: the JavaScript isn't executed until its in the browser, so you can dynamically generate it. you'll need to figure out how to omit the last `,` though as that will mess up IE

Comment: Excellent.  If it's working, you should accept the answer to show that this solution is correct.  Thanks!